# Mongodb collection not updating properly after webscraping new values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord.js, cheerio, request-promise

Working on a webscraping bot, that when a user uses !stats in discord chat, it displays their stats that are scraped from a site using cheerio. Everytime the command is called, the site is scraped and the new stats are pulled. However the issue is I am having difficulty updating the new values in mongodb Please see commented console.logs for the issue. Any help would be appreciated, feel like i am missing something super simple. Ive tried find, findOne, and findOneAndUpdate and all have the same issue.

```
Stats.find({}, 'userId', { '_id': 0 }, function (err, docs) {

        for (i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
            ids.push(docs[i].userId);
        }

        /////

        ids.forEach(function (entry) {
            var userUrl = 'https://popflash.site/user/' + entry;



            rp(userUrl)
                .then(function (html) {
                    const arr = [];
                    var e = 0;

                    $('.stat-container', html).each(function (key, value) {
                        arr[e++] = $(this).find(".stat").text();

                    });



                    var results = arr.map(Number)
                   console.log(results); //this is printing the newly scraped stats from the site which is working fine.

                    var query = { userId: entry };

                    Stats.find(query, {
                        $set: {
                            HLTV: results[0],
                            ADR: results[1],
                            HS: results[2],
                            W: results[3],
                            L: results[4],
                            T: results[5],
                            totalGames: results[3] + results[4],
                            win_percent: results[6]
                        }
                    })
                        .then(function (result) {

                                    console.log(result) //this is displaying old stats that are stored in the db, seems to not be updating.
                        })

                })
        }); 

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running a `find` query, of course the result will be what is already in the database. If you want to `update` the db, you need to use `update` method.

```
Stats.update(query, {
   $set: {
       HLTV: results[0],
       ADR: results[1],
       HS: results[2],
       W: results[3],
       L: results[4],
       T: results[5],
       totalGames: results[3] + results[4],
       win_percent: results[6]
   }
})
```

Comment: lol, I figured I was over complicating things, new to mongodb. Worked, thanks man!

Comment: @tru2793 In the future, I suggest reading mongo docs... or googling something along the lines of "mongo how to update document". In the meantime please accept my answer if it was in fact the solution to your problem.

Comment: If the answer helped you and solved the problem please press the green tick next to the answer to mark your question as resolved.